# How to get a list of the feature files to be run before they start

Tags: c#, specflow, feature-file

When I run specflow i choose specific feature files to be tested. 
I need to build virtual machine in order to run my tests and I want to build only the required environments for the testing (and sure it can be dynamically change) so I need to know (maybe in BeforeTestRun hook) how can I get list of the selected features to be run.

Thanks.

edit---------------
The flow is: I mark some of the features I want to test,
2. I right click "Run selected tests"
3. I want to be able to have something like:
string[] featuresToRun = Specflow.GetFeaturesToTest();

Comment: Share some code and flow

Comment: edit---------------
The flow is: I mark some of the features I want to test,
2. I right click "Run selected tests"
3. I want to be able to have something like:
string[] featuresToRun = Specflow.GetFeaturesToTest();

Comment: Which test runner are you using?

Comment: TechTalk (if this what you meant :DD)